# Can I change a drop down item from a list in Jsoup and submit it?

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I have a site I'm trying to scrape with Jsoup that has monthly and yearly selection boxes where the data changes when a different month or year is selected. Edit* The data changes as soon as the month or year is changed and there is no submit button.

[image]

Default is always this month and year which I can scrape but I'm hoping to scrape historic data for previous months and years by selecting different values in the drop-downs.

I can find the Element where the drop-down is placed but no matter what I've tried, I can't make a selection and change the month via Jsoup. Is it possible to change the "option selected value" and submit it via a FormElement?

I've included the code and a System.out.println() where the code is based.

```
                Connection.Response resp = Jsoup.connect(url) //
                    .timeout(30000) //
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET) //
                    .execute();
            
            Document doc = resp.parse();
            Element pForm = doc.selectFirst("select:nth-of-type(2)");
            System.out.println(pForm.toString());
    // Result:
//<select name="month" size="1" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;text-align: left; font-family: Arial Narrow; font-size: 10" onchange="this.form.submit();"> <option value="June">June</option> <option value="July">July</option> <option value="August">August</option> <option value="September">September</option> <option value="October">October</option> <option value="November">November</option> <option value="December">December</option> <option value="January">January</option> <option value="February">February</option> <option value="March">March</option> <option value="April">April</option> <option selected value="May">May</option> </select>
```

Comment: to my knowledge jsoup is a library for parsing HTML (input with various methods) but not really suitable to send form requests. I recommend that you first fetch the html manually to find out about the forms structure - add the `<form>` tag and the `<select>` tags of the dropdowns to your question. If the available values change with various input values, you can fetch the necessary available data with jsoup, but you (we) should analyze the form structure manually. Then we can help you how to tell jsoup to fetch the page with a suitable request and change input data.

Comment: There is an onchange "form" in that Element above. The only other form "tag" I can find is 
       <form method="POST" name="fixtures" action="fixturesall.php"></form>
 
The only "select" I can find is in the Element already posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send a POST request (instead of a GET) with the `<form>` you described in the comments. The onchange-event just does submit the form as soon as you change the value of the dropdown.
According to the docs on https://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url you would add the form data and send the request like this:

```java
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
    .timeout(30000)
    .data("month", "June")
    .post();
```

This will set the "fixtures" select to the value "June". Take care that your `url` points to the form action ("fixturesall.php"), as the HTML does not contain any path this is relative to the path you requested the initial page from.

As the screenshot showed multiple selects, it might be necessary to add further parameters to your form request. I'm not sure (didn't test it) if JSoup allows adding up multiple calls to `.data()` or if one data call replaces the previous. According to the [JavaDoc](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#data(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) I would think that data adds up.
To be sure, you can also provide a `Map` to `data()` that contains multiple key-value pairs.

Comment: This worked perfectly although "fixtures" should have been "month". Yes there are other drop-downs but the data can be stacked:

      Document document = Jsoup.connect(url)
           .timeout(30000)
           .data("season", "201920")
           .data("month", "March")
           .post();

Comment: Nice. Just updated the form field name in the answer, don't know what I got it wrong in the first attempt.